# css div won't center

Tags: html, css

I've been searching this site for answers to this question, but none have worked or I already had the given answer within my code. So, here's my code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400italic,300,500italic,300italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700);
html {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.the-big-image {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(img/rocks.jpg);
}
.the-big-image-cover {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* Standard syntax */
}
nav {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%
}
.brand-logo {
  font-family: quicksand, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
}
.hamburger-container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  dispaly: inline-block;
}
.icon-bar {
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="the-big-image">
    <div class="the-big-image-cover">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <span class="brand-logo text-center">logo</span>
          <button class="hamburger-container right">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="divider"></div>`
```

I really just want to know why class `.brand-logo` will not center. I set a width for it. I set the width on it. I made sure it wasn't a block element. I added the margin code with auto. Why won't it work?

Comment: it is helpful to answerers and to future readers if you strip out all unnecessary code. creating a bare-minimum example that still shows the problem will also help you locate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Gunaseelan Not sure a JSFiddle is required as OP has provided a stack snippet.

Comment: The answer is not text-aligning your parent (container).

Comment: @woodrowbarlow I know that i <em>Should</em> strip down my code, but it looked pretty  and would be a shame for ppl not to see it. Besides, had i strippeed it down to where i wanted to in the first place, The answer couldn't be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon in your CSS for the parent element.  Fixing that and adding text-align: center; worked for me.  Try this.

```
.nav-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: He did miss a semicolon, but that is not the problem he is having.

Comment: I also addressed the specific problem with my answer, but I felt the missing semicolon was worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks man. I swear my impatience gets the best of me. I appreciate the help though! I just added the text-center class to the nav-wrapper and it all works. Thanks man!

Comment: Joseph: it worked. Semicolon wasn't my problem, but i wanted clean code, so it was worth it.

Comment: Adding a text-align to the parent div is the butcher's block method. He should be defining the width for his children.

Comment: Adding auto left and right margins to a child and text-align: center to the parent guarantees the element will be centered in all modern browsers.   I have yet to find any other method that always works, so this is my preferred fix.   There are cases where you may not always want to define the width of an element, if your site has any type of dynamic content.

Answer (score 4):

Your logo is centered in your span, but your span is not the full width of the navbar. Pull your logo out into a new div with absolute positioning, and center it within that div. See example below:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400italic,300,500italic,300italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700);
html {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.the-big-image {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(img/rocks.jpg);
}
.the-big-image-cover {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 77, 64, 0.28), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* Standard syntax */
}
nav {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%
}
.brand-logo {
  font-family: quicksand, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
}
.hamburger-container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  dispaly: inline-block;
}
.icon-bar {
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.logoDiv{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="the-big-image">
    <div class="the-big-image-cover">
      <nav>
        <div class="logoDiv">
          <span class="brand-logo text-center">logo</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <button class="hamburger-container right">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="divider"></div>`
```

Comment: An easy way to understand this is by inserting this <span class="brand-logo text-center">logo<br/>..</span>

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` in `.nav-wrapper`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/71qb2dfc/1/)

Comment: the logo in the fiddle does not seem to be centered

Answer (score 0):

You must `text-align: center` the parent div. You have `text-align: center` for the `.brand-logo` class and that alone won't center the logo. It's the parent that must have `text-align` set to `center` in order to center its contents.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey3dv1ru/)

```
.nav-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Aligning the parent div could work if he was wanting to also align the menu button. He is only wanting the logo aligned. The solution is proper usage of grid layout. He has child elements without a defined width. The solution is adding the defined width to his children.

Comment: @JosephCasey, try to remove the `text-align: center` from the `.nav-wrapper` and see if it affects the button. **Update**: the OP just showed how _right_ you are. Thanks for the downvote though

Comment: not sure why this got a minus? Your answer is correct!

Comment: @Chiapa you're still missing the point. He's floating the menu object. You can rig CSS to look right by using it in an improper manner. It will be fine until you start to scale the css up to enterprise productions. Your solution is a poor man's hack, and it shouldn't be practiced because it is a fundamental misunderstanding of how css was intended to work.

Comment: @JosephCasey, the OP accepted and explained what solution he used. You are saying these aren't the correct answers, I'm sure you know a better way. You know what you could do instead of downvoting everyone else's answers? You could come up with an answer yourself, better than everyone else's: I'll be here to upvote it